# Finding QObject which is not part of qobjects hierarchy

Tags: qt, qt5, qt6

In a debug build I would like particular objects of my program to register themselves in some global registry so I can have a view in my app detecting them and showing theirs statuses.

As all of them are `QObject`s I was wondering if there is a clever way of registering them in some global `QObject`s list (which I am not aware of). I cannot use regular hierarchy as some of these objects simply never become a child of any other `QObject`.

Comment: Just today i was thinking about this when `-widgetcount` gave me 4 undeleted widgets. Undeleted QObjects must be in the thousands then. Have you thought about some solutions yet? I was thinking it should be possible to leverage the metaobject to get the name of the class to be able to find the leak.

Comment: I don't really understand why you don't want all of your QObjects to have parent/child relationships in the regular hierarchy, but for those orphaned objects could you make them the child of some other QObject? That way all of your objects would either be part of the regular hierarchy or the orphan hierarchy.

Comment: @JarMan: many of these `QObject`s are simply created on stack in `main()` or are members of other classes.

Answer (score 1):

Since `QApplication` inherits `QObject` you could just set your active `QApplication` as parent of all `QObjects` not fitting into your normal application tree. After closing all windows you could then check all children of `QApplication` for leaked `QObjects` by calling `const QObjectList & QObject::children() const`.